# Google Play services and firebase

Tags: android

I'm developing a firebase app the version of firebase is about 9.6. I want to know if the version of firebase for my app same as the version of Google play service that will come with it.

Comment: You need to check this documentation https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#add_google_play_services_to_your_project

Comment: Thanks so much Amrish.